# How to add gaps using geom_tile in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot a heatmap using geom_tile (ggplot2):

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")

x <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3)
rownames(x) <- LETTERS[1:3]
colnames(x) <- letters[1:4]
x_melted <- melt(x)
x_melted$group1 <- rep(c("T1","T2"), each=6)

ggplot(x_melted, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

But I need add a gap according to `group1` in `x_melted` so that a gap was produced between the first two rows and the last two rows. How could this be added?
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible or at least I've never seen a solution. One possible workaround is to plot each separately then merge together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use facets -

```
x_melted$group1 = factor(x_melted$group1, levels = c("T2", "T1"))

ggplot(x_melted, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  facet_grid(group1 ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]